Der offenkundigen Absicht der neuen Regierung?
I am reading an article in FAZ (https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/keir-starmers-labour-regierung-das-sind-ihre-ersten-schritte-19921840.html) and found this sentence a bit weird to me (grammatically).

Der offenkundigen Absicht der neuen Regierung, auf diese Weise soziale
Ruhe herzustellen, widerspricht nicht unbedingt die Streichung der
verbreitetsten Sozialleistung für viele Rentner.

Since Absicht is feminine I guess the sentence should start with Die offenkundigen, no?

Absicht is feminine, but it is in dative case. The subject, which in this sentence is Streichung, is in nominative case. Maybe it is the word order that confuses you. So let's get rid of the irrelevant words:

Der offenkundigen Absicht(dative) … widerspricht … die Streichung(nominative) …

The default word order would be:

Die Streichung(nominative) … widerspricht … der offenkundigen Absicht(dative) …


Thanks for your explanation. You are right. I was confused. I thought that the subject was Absicht.

@mkim No wonder you're confused. The original sentence is very bad style imo.
